# How can I nest an If statement in a substr function in R

Tags: r, if-statement, substr

I am trying to pull apart a numeric field into two parts so I can merge with another data set. The number of characters is 6 or 7 characters long. I was able to get the last characters easily enough, but now I need either the first one or two characters of the field, depending on how long it is. This was my stab at it, but I received a number of errors. Is it possible to nest an If statement like this? Or do I need to swap it and run an If statement in a loop with different assignment statements?

```
df$new_field <- as.numeric(substr(df$GEOID, 1 ,if(nchar(df$GEOID)=6){
  return(1)
}
else{
  return(2)
}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With can use `ifelse` instead of `if/else` as `ifelse` is vectorized while `if/else` takes only a single value of length 1 and returns length 1

```
df$new_field <- with(df, as.numeric(substr(GEOID, 1, 
                             ifelse(nchar(GEOID) == 6, 1, 2))))
```

---

Or another option is to convert the logical vector to numeric

```
n  <- (nchar(df$GEOID) != 6) + 1
df$new_field <- with(df, as.numeric(substr(GEOID, 1, n)))
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
v1 <- c('1234567', '123456', '1234')
n  <- (nchar(v1) != 6) + 1
n
#[1] 2 1 2
substr(v1, 1, n)
#[1] "12" "1"  "12"
```

NOTE: In addition to `substr`, `substring` can also be used with the same method

Answer (score 0):

We can use `substring`

```
df$new_field <- substring(df$GEOID, 1, c(1, 2)[(nchar(df$GEOID) == 7) + 1])
df$new_field
#[1] "A"  "D"  "AB"
```

OR with `sub` and regex.

```
with(df, ifelse(nchar(GEOID) == 7, sub('(..).*', '\\1', GEOID), 
                                   sub('(.).*', '\\1', GEOID)))
#[1] "A"  "D"  "AB"
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(GEOID = c('ABCDEF', 'DEFABC', 'ABCDEFG'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```